# Haskell - Matching regex only at the beginning of string (not beginning of each line!)

Tags: regex, haskell

I am trying to match a pattern, but only if it appears at the beginning of the string (notice the beginning of the string, not the beginning of each line). The only way I found is using the "`" anchor:

```
text =~ "\`text in the beginning"
```

but for long strings without a match, it is very slow, I guess it tries to find a match throughout the whole text.

Suggestions?

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes to my question and my solution? It would be helpful to learn so I don't do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Success! The answer was using non-multiline regular expressions. I implemented my own matching operator:

```
(=~+) text pattern = match (makeRegexOpts blankCompOpt defaultExecOpt pattern :: Regex) text
```

`blankComptOpt` (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-tdfa-1.2.3.1/docs/Text-Regex-TDFA.html#t:CompOption) is what deactivates multiline matching.

```
Prelude Text.Regex.TDFA> "blahblah\nmeh" =~+ "^meh" :: Bool
False
Prelude Text.Regex.TDFA> "meh\nblahblah" =~+ "^meh" :: Bool
True
```

And for my larger input it runs very fast.

Answer (score 1):

The regular way to denote a match at the beginning is with `^`:

```
text =~ "^text in the beginning"
```

Have you tried that? If you did and it failed for you, please specify which regex library you are using. I just verified with `regex-posix` and `regex-pcre-builtin`, and both work fine for me.

But if you really just want to match on a prefix, why not use `isPrefixOf` instead? There are versions [for `String`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.7/base-4.12.0.0/Data-List.html#v:isPrefixOf), [for `Text`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.7/text-1.2.3.1/Data-Text.html#v:isPrefixOf), and [for `ByteString`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.7/bytestring-0.10.8.2/Data-ByteString.html#v:isPrefixOf). Way more efficient than regex.

Comment: (Downvote because it didn't answer the question, but I appreciate the discussion. I hope it is the correct way?)

The problem with the caret anchor is that it matches the beginning of every line, ie 
`"blahblah\nmeh" =~ "\\`meh" :: Bool` returns False (as I expect), but `"blahblah\nmeh" =~ "^meh" :: Bool` returns True.
And I want it to be False. And I need regex, because it is unfortunately a mess of plain text format file that I have to parse. Honestly I have not looked into isPrefixOf yet, it might cut it. But I was curious about how to do this.